# Работа со скриптами в Bash

Tags: bash, if, case

Есть домашнее задание по Bash.

Напишите скрипт. При запуске будет задан вопрос об указании пути до директории и создать, если ее нет.
Если директория существует – пользователю выводится сообщение, что директория существует.

При запуске скрипта должно выйти сообщение "Введите путь:"
Я ввожу путь (например /home/user/testdir) и если эта директория существует, то должно выйти сообщение, что она есть.
Если же нет такой директории, то скрипт должен ее создать.

Как понимаю, начало должно быть такое
echo -n "Введите путь:"
Read

Чтобы создать директорию, если ее нет с помощью if-then-else, я знаю что прописать (создал простой скрипт и проверил). А вот как всё это объединить, чтобы работало - не понимаю. Использовать операторы if и case желательно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делается это примерно вот так:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "enter path"

read path

if [ -d "$path" ]
 then
    echo "$path exist"
else
    mkdir $path
fi
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я что-то переменную Path упустил. Я только учусь :)

Comment: Можно обойтись без `echo` ведь у `read` есть опция `-p`, позволяющая вывести сообщение для понимания происходящего:
`read -p "Введите путь: " path` и `mkdir` лучше использовать с опцией `-p`, правда здесь она имееет другой смысл:   `-p, --parents      не выдавать ошибку, если существует; создавать родительские каталоги при необходимости`
И переменную `$path` стоит обернуть в `""`: `mkdir -p "$path"`.